# Problema com Post ajax e Objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um função construtora que vai montar um objeto para mim:

```
var companyConstructor = function Company(id, logo, name, language, primaryColor, secondaryColor, description, headOffice, serverInfo, serverAddress, publicUrl) {

    if (false === (this instanceof Company)) {
        return new Company();
    }

    this.id = id;
    this.logo = logo;
    this.name = name;
    this.language = language;
    this.primaryColor = primaryColor;
    this.secondaryColor = secondaryColor;
    this.description = description;
    this.headOffice = headOffice;
    this.serverInfo = serverInfo;
    this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    this.publicUrl = publicUrl;
    this.users = [];
};
```

E também tenho um método no `prototype` desta função que adiciona usuários no objeto:

```
companyConstructor.prototype.add = function (data) {

    var o = {
        id: data.Id,
        name: data.Name,
        email: data.Email                        
    };

    return this.users.push(o);
};
```

Depois eu crio uma instância deste objeto e no decorrer da tela vou preenchendo este objeto:

`var company = new companyConstructor();`

O Problema é que quando dou um post passando este objeto `company`, ele entra na função de `add` do `prototype` e da um erro pois não acha as propriedades.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/company/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',                
    data: company,
    success: function (data) {                    

    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
});
```

Pelo fato da função `add` ser herdada não pensei que ela seria disparada no post, acho que algo está errado, alguém poderia me explicar.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined`

Ele não está conseguindo achar a propriedade `Id` que está dentro da função `.add` no prototype do objeto, é este erro que está dando no console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta não é propriamente uma solução, é mais uma constatação. Segundo a documentação do jQuery, quando usados objectos no `data` eles têm de ser objectos simples:

> **data**
>   Type: *PlainObject or String*
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. **Object must be Key/Value pairs.** If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

**A parte a negrito diz:** *Objectos têm de ser pares chave/valor*

Assim o jQuery vai correr tudo o que fôr funções para obter o seu resultado e serializa-lo. Não estou a ver como consegue dar a volta a esse problema. Já tentou outra biblioteca?

Comment: Entendi, então acho que vou modificar a forma que está feito para no final ter um objeto simples, sem herança com o `prototype`.

Comment: @fbadaro, acho melhor também. Já agora pode experimentar usando MooTools. O código seria: http://jsfiddle.net/gtkZL/